# I have created secured server with PSK-NULL-SHA256 with no certificate but when try to connect with client provides handshake failure

Tags: tls, openssl

**Server side :** 
I have created the secure SSL server using openssl command with no certificate to verify using cipher suite PSK-NULL-SHA256 with preshared key "AD" with dummy key and PSK identity as given below which results in server is created and waiting for client to connect with.

```
openssl.exe s_server -accept 4020 -cipher PSK-NULL-SHA256 -psk AD -psk_hint testing.domain.0106 -nocert tls1_2**
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
```

**Client side :** 
Below command is given in client to connect with using same cipher and port mentioned in server but ends up with the error mentioned below .

```
openssl.exe s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:4020 -psk AD -psk_identity domain.0010 -tls1_2
```

**Error in client side :**

```
CONNECTED(00000004) <br/>
25769803792:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake <br/>failure:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40<br/>
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 246 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)<br/>
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported<br/>
Compression: NONE<br/>
Expansion: NONE<br/>
No ALPN negotiated<br/>
SSL-Session:<br/>
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2<br/>
    Cipher    : 0000<br/>
    Session-ID:<br/>
    Session-ID-ctx:<br/>
    Master-Key:<br/>
    PSK identity: None<br/>
    PSK identity hint: None<br/>
    SRP username: None<br/>
    Start Time: 1592417575<br/>
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)<br/>
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)<br/>
    Extended master secret: no<br/>
---
```

**Error in server side:**

```
ERROR
25769803792:error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher:ssl/statem/statem_srvr.c:2284:
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
```

Why is the connection being terminated with alert number `40`? Can anyone please let me know the rationale behind it?

Comment: Have you googled "SSL alert number 40"? There are a bunch of solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can look up TLS magic numbers on the [TLS parameter registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml), including [alerts](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-6). 40 is “handshake failure”, which doesn't tell you much.

The reason for the handshake failure is clearly indicated in the server output: “no shared cipher”.

> Below command is given in client to connect with using same cipher and port mentioned in server

Well, no. You did not specify a cipher suite.

By default, OpenSSL does not allow insecure cipher suites such as cipher suites without encryption (`…-NULL-…`). See the [`ciphers`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html) man page (linked from the `s_client` and `s_server` man pages). You have to enable them explicitly with a `-cipher` option, e.g.

```
openssl.exe s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:4020 -psk AD -psk_identity domain.0010 -tls1_2 -cipher eNULL
```

Comment: I have tried to include -cipher eNULL  in client side as you suggested but i end up in getting error - "NO CIPHERS AVAILABLE" . Error message is attached below 25769803792:error:141A90B5:SSL routines:ssl_cipher_list_to_bytes:no ciphers available:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:3795:No ciphers enabled for max supported SSL/TLS version
---
no peer certificate available

Comment: 'SO-stop being - I could not able to make it even with "cipher eNULL" command . Does it worked for you